# VB.NET How to detect which textbox is active and insert data on it

Tags: textbox, focus

Welcome

I have 3 textboxes and one button

When I click on this button , I want to check which textbox is active , the cursor of mouse is on it and put the data on these text box

For Example in my button it will check which one is active and put data ( anything ) on it

I need your help

Thanks

Comment: I think when you click the button , the button is becomming active. Or You mean after the click then point the textbox you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Me.ActiveControl`.

Comment: That would become the button. Because the user just click the button.

Comment: You can use it before clicking the button and store the value in a variable.

Comment: The problem is I dn't understand the OP whether he want the textbox before or after. If it is what you say. We may need to raised events.